# Firebase Endlessly Generates My Project ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

Whenever I try to create a firebase project in the console it won't let me continue and just endlessly tries to generate my project ID. I've tried many times but it just won't work. It is very frustrating.

Edit - So I tried on my Samsung phone and it worked, I think it may of had to do with the fact that I'm on a macbook. However, it still won't let me open the project on my mac even once I created it on my phone.

Comment: Is there any error message showing in the UI of the console, or in the JavaScript developer console of your browser?

Comment: No, the continue button just stays grey and locked

Comment: Hmm... that is quite unexpected. Since I don't see other reports about such a problem at the moment, I suspect it is something local to your system or account. Can you try on another browser and on another network? If the problem also occurs there, it might be worth to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting - as they can check if your account is in some unexpected state.